# Ввод значений в Edit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Как сделать вывод спец символов в Edit? что бы можно было указывать в Edit1.Text символы которые удалить ?

```
if s[i] in ['!', '+'] then
    Delete(s, i, 1)
```

Если делаю вот так

```
if s[i] in CharinSet(edit1.Text) // то получаю ошибку
    Delete(s, i, 1)
```

Как быть в этой ситуации ?

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли **всегда** указывайте **оригинальное** сообщение об ошибке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```pascal
var
  testSet: TSysCharSet;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Преобразуем строку, введенную в Edit1 в множество
  testSet := [];
  for i := 1 to Length(Edit1.Text) do
    Include(testSet, Edit1.Text[i]);

  // Проверяем символы строки на принадлежность множеству
  for i := Length(s) downto 1 do begin  // Принципиально, что цикл в обратном порядке
    if CharinSet(s[i], testSet) then
      Delete(s, i, 1);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   //if Key in ['0'..'9'] then key :=#0; //ввод букв и символов
   //if not(key in['0'..'9',#8])then key:=#0;  //ввод только цифр
   //if not(key in['А'..'Я','0'..'9','а'..'я',#8])then key:=#0;  //ввод всего кроме символов
end;
```