# В EditText можно ли проверить сколько слов ввели в поле?

Tags: android, edittext

Используется EditText. Надо, чтобы пользователь мог ввести только одно слово, не больше. Как проверить сколько он ввел слов или ограничить число слов одним при начальном вводе?

Comment: при вводе в поле не давать вставить пробел? и тогда будет всегда одно слово

Comment: А как не дать вставить пробел

Comment: по аналогии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1307725/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-edit/1307747#1307747